# General information or tips about eval(parse(

Tags: r, parsing, eval

In my R script I am using quite often the function

```
eval(parse(text=paste(....
```

However, by reading many posts on this forum many people say it's not the best way to proceed. May anyone tell me why this solution is not suitable?

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Because there are better ways to do it without using the `eval(parse(.`  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's not really a problem because it works but I was wondering why it's not recommended to use it? Is it not stable in big loops or something like that?

Comment: The dupe link may give some info.